# Browsing Swagger hosted on IIS Express not working using Firefox Quantum

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, iis-express, firefox-quantum

Has anyone else seen an issue with the new Firefox Quantum Browser when trying to browse Swagger on localhost using IISExpress?

OS: Windows 10

IDE: Visual Studio 2017

Broswer: Firefox Quantum 57.0.2 (64-bit)

The application that I am working on is launched from Visual Studio with the debugger attached and uses IISExpress to host the application.

When I launch my application which takes me to my Swagger endpoint for my API, Firefox Quantum is successfully launched and attempts to display my localhost instance that is served by IIS Express, however I get a "File not found" - "Firefox can't find the file at http://localhost:65232/swagger/ui/index."

[image: File not found]

If I then visit the same localhost URL using Chrome, the application is found and rendered as expected.

It is also worth mentioning that this is only a problem in Firefox when running on IISExpress, once deployed in a production/test environment, Firefox serves the application perfectly fine.

Has anyone else experienced similar issues with Firefox Quantum? I would really like to continue working with Firefox and not go back to Chrome but at the moment it is looking like I may have to.

### Update:

- It looks like Firefox is receiving a 403 Forbidden response from IISExpress
- My content type is application/x-protobuf so I wonder if Firefox has an issue with this locally?

Comment: I have the same setup and no issues with Firefox, can you create a minimal app reproducing your issue and post a link, I can try it on my machine...